# Move all files and Subdirectories from a folder to another Subdirectory of the same folder

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, directory, subdirectory

I want to move all files and subdirectories including files to another subdirectory of the same folder.

e.g. I have folder named abcd inside I have a file aa and subfolders bb, cc, dd.
SO I would like to create another subdirectory inside the same folder as abcd\backup
and move aa, bb, cc, dd i.e. all files and folder to backup folder.

Comment: I could not find any problem in here

Comment: Could you share that you have tried

Answer (score 2):

This is gonna be very simple.

```
Directory.Move("SourcePath", "DestinationPath");
```

Process all directories in the source folder and use the above syntax for each and every folder using forloop or foreach to move to your destination folder.

Comment: SA not asking for moving files, he want a backup so Copy is a good thing.

Comment: This won't work for a network path: \\server\folder\. It will throw an exception, that it can not find a path part

Comment: @anindis wouldn't Server.MapPath() resolve that issue?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, this will move and remove the Source directory, question asks for all files and folders in directory to move to a sub folder (maintaining structure).

Answer (score 1):

```
        string source = @"d:\test";
        string dest = @"d:\move\";

        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(dest);
        if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);


        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(source);
        DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();


        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(source);
        Int32 i = dirs.Count() + files.Count();
        //   for progress bar

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
                string destFile = Path.Combine(dest, name);
                // skip some file
                if (name != "file") File.Move(file, destFile);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
        {
            string temppath = Path.Combine(dest, subdir.Name);
            if (!Directory.Exists(temppath))
                try
                {
                    Directory.Move(subdir.FullName, temppath);
                }
                catch
                {

                }
        }
```